# Why is index matching failing on a list of links?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a web scraper that returns a list of links for articles on a page. The links have dates in them (example: https://ria.ru/20190826/1557929866.html is from August (08) 2019). I want to remove links that don't meet a given date parameter from my list. My match function is not working, and I am not sure why.

I can cycle through the list of links and print from [15:21]. This returns the correct values. So I do not think it is an index issue. I think it is a matching issue.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

# Create list for links

links = []

# pull the HTML

html = urlopen("https://ria.ru/search/?query=mcdonalds")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Collect all article links, which all have a 
# data-url attribute and are in span tags and add them to a list

for link in bsObj.findAll("span"):
    if 'data-url' in link.attrs:
        links.append(link.attrs['data-url'])

# Remove links that do not meet data parameters from the list
# This is the problematic code. 

for link in links:
    if (link[15:21]) != "201905":
    `    links.remove(link)

print(links)
```

The returned list of links is shorter, but includes links that do not meet the date criteria.

For example

['https://ria.ru/20190813/1557454474.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190725/1556861008.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190705/1556244317.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190530/1555087647.html']

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1207406) Or, do the filtering during the first loop.

Comment: As @JohnnyMopp commented, your problem is that you're removing items from a list _while you're iterating over it_, which isn't safe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try a list comprehension instead:

```py
links = [link for link in links if link[15:21] == "201905"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to delete items in a list that you are also in the process of iterating through. This makes you remove things you don't want to remove, and possibly not remove things you want to.

So here, we simply enumerate the list and store the indexes we want to remove once we are done iterating. Afterwards, we remove the indexes in reverse order because if we remove in normal order we will change the index of everything after the index we remove. By removing backwards, we do not impact other indexes we want to remove.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Create list for links

links = []

# pull the HTML

html = urlopen("https://ria.ru/search/?query=mcdonalds")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Collect all article links, which all have a
# data-url attribute and are in span tags and add them to a list

for link in bsObj.findAll("span"):
    if 'data-url' in link.attrs:
        links.append(link.attrs['data-url'])

# Remove links that do not meet data parameters from the list
# This is the problematic code.

remove = []
for index, link in enumerate(reversed(links)):
    if (link[15:21]) != "201905":
        remove.append(index)

for index in reversed(remove):
    del links[index]

print(links)
```

Output

```
['https://ria.ru/20181115/1532878009.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180927/1529462687.html']
```

Alternatively, you could just construct a new list of only the links you want instead of removing the links from your existing list of lings. But hopefully that helps you understand the why.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Don't forget to select as the answer if it answered your question.